# He went to work vs. went to the work

Tags: articles

1. He went to work.
2. He went to the work.

Is #2 correct as used differently from #1 (Verb vs. noun)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Work* is a noun in both sentences.

When saying someone went to the the place they work at, you always say:

> X went to work.

When you say,

> X went to the work.

I can only think that X went over to a work of art. It would have to be a very specific situation.

Comment: "went to work" can also mean "started working"; "went to the work" suggests "the work" is a location/physical item.

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is ambiguous. *To work* can be either a prepositional phrase or the to-infinitive.
You can use both in one sentence:

> He went to work to work.

The first *work* is a noun (place of employment), the second a verb (to work). You can use *in order to* instead of *to* to see that this is a prepositional phrase

> He went to work in order to work.

It is usually easy to decide whether *to work* is a prepositional phrase or the to-infinitive by what follows the two words. But, without more context, each of the following could be read as a noun or verb:

> He went to work in Chicago.
>
> He went to work at 9 AM.

One reason this is so is because *to go to work* can mean both *to go to one's  place of employment* and *to get busy (or to start) doing a task*. The same ambiguity can be seen in *get to work*.

> I need to get to work

can mean

> I need to get to my place of employment

or

> I need to start working (on a task)

As a noun, when we mean the place where we work, we  use *to work*, without the definite article. We also say *to school* and *to home*. If you say *to the work* it means something else, depending on context.

> We went to the work

It could be a *work of art* or some other object.